# Setup script variables before attaching to an object

Tags: unity

I need to attach a script at runtime, but that script requires some public members to be set in order to be helpful. Is there a way for me to setup the public members of the script before attaching it to a GameObject at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***Start()*** method and ***Update()*** method of the component will be called after the frame you add them.

So you can set all your public variables right after the line you add them.

The only thing you should be careful about is the ***Awake()*** method, which is called at the instant that you add the component.

Here is a brief summary of the execution order after you call ***AddComponent()***:

1. ***Awake()*** method of the component
2. The rest of the method that you added component from (the method that called ***AddComponent()***)
3. ***Start()*** method of the component
4. ***Update()*** method of the component

So, in the second step, you can safely setup component's variables that has nothing to do with Awake().